# How to add print(.....),println(..) to String scala

Tags: scala

```
def logic(n : Int):String = {
    var rows = Math.pow(2,n).toInt;
    var i = 0;
    var str : String = "";
   for(i<-0 until rows)
    {
     var j = n-1 ;
      for(j<-(0 to n-1).reverse)
      {
        str+=(print((i/(Math.pow(2,j).toInt))%2)).toString;
      }
      str+=(println()).toString;
    }
   println(str.toString);
   return str.toString;}
```

When i run println(postfix) i just see a lot of () help me to add print((i/(Math.pow(2,j).toInt))%2) into a string.Thanks

Comment: what.............??

Answer (score 1):

`print` and `println` doesn't return a `String`, it prints to the standard output. The `()` you are seeing in the console is scala `Unit` - which is a tuple of 0 elements, since `print` and `println` return `Unit` (which is similar in terms of semantics to javas `void`). To append the evaluated String value of your calculation simply do this

```
str += ((1 / (Math.pow(2, 1).toInt)) % 2).toString
```

Then use `print` or `println` to output it to the standard out:

```
println(str)
```

However, to make your code more idiomatic, I would look at

- `mkString` on collections ([random resource](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-convert-array-to-string-mkstring))
- string interpolation ([docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html))

Looking at those a bit more concise solution:

```
def truthtable(n: Int) = (0 until Math.pow(2, n).toInt).map { i =>
  (0 to n - 1).reverse.map(j => (i / (Math.pow(2, j).toInt)) % 2).mkString("")
}.mkString("\n")
```

This returns the truthtable as a String then all you have to do is print it:

```
println(truthtable(5))
```

Note that I didn't check if your algorithm is correct, just refactored what you already have.

Comment: when i see your answer ,I realize my question was very stupid @@ Thank you very much

Comment: sr but i have another question, i want to but that truthtable(5) into a txt file,so i add it to a string but when i open a txt file i just see it 00011011 not

Comment: @BlackZero, Ask it as another question rather than a comment here.

Comment: sr but i have another question, i want to but that truthtable(5) into a txt file,so i add it to a string but when i open a txt file i just see it 00011011 not   00
        01
       10
       11

Comment: @BlackZero Yep it's the "stackoverflow way" to keep the question focused on one topic. Also in the new question pls post the relevant code which writes the String to the file, not the whole truthtable logic, since that adds an extra layer of irrelevant code people have to read through :)